# while taking count of two column result is not showing proper

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Driverperformance] 
    @Ecode nvarchar(50), 
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime
as 
begin 

    declare @date1 datetime = CONVERT(datetime, @startdate + ' 00:01:00.000', 120);
    declare @date2 datetime = CONVERT(datetime, @enddate + ' 23:23:59.000', 120);

    SELECT 
        e.Ecode,CAST(q.dtime AS DATE) as Date, 
        e.Ename, 
        count(q.Ecode) CntEcode ,
        count(DelEcode) CntDelEcode
    FROM EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
    inner JOIN Transaction_tbl q 
        ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode where q.Ecode=@Ecode
        and dtime between '' + @date1 +'' and ''+@date2+'' 
    group by 
        e.Ecode, 
        e.Ename, 
        CAST(q.dtime AS date) 
    ORDER BY CAST(q.dtime AS date)--e.Ecode DESC
end
```

but i am not getting Count of DelEcode proper ,what is wrong with my stored procedure
while i am checking count of DelEcode like this:select * from Transaction_tbl where dtime >='2013-09-03 00:00:00.000' and dtime <='2013-09-03 23:59:59.000' and DelEcode='E003' am getting 35 rows,but while executing the store procedure am getting only 23 counts of CntDelEcode

Comment: **1.** Learn to format your code properly. It helps you and helps others working with your codebase. **2.** Make the effort of describing your table structure, the data, what output you expect and what output you get.

Comment: Well, for a start, your date comparison is bonkers.

Comment: What does it mean? `and dtime between '' + @date1 +'' and ''+@date2+''`

Comment: i want to get result between satarting time of corresponding date and ending time of corresponding date

Comment: You want to exclude anything that happened at, say, 23:59:59.357? For continua like time, it's almost always better to use a semi-open interval (`>=` start point, `<` end point) rather than use `BETWEEN`.

Comment: no,,sir..i want to get things happened at last moment of particular date'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of different "DelEcode" try count(distinct DelEcode). If not, you are going to count the number of records with not null DelEcode values. If you perform a join the count will be the result of the cartesian product, not the number of different DelEcodes.

Comment: so where i have to change in my procedure

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use SQL Server 2008 or later as you have a `CAST(... as date)` in your code

There are several issues with your stored procedure:

1. A weird way to strip time (just cast to date)
2. A BETWEEN statement that compares **strings** instead of dates, because of the `+''` statements.
3. Using `datetime` parameters when you actually need just `date`

The simplest way would be to rewrite the stored procedure like this

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Driverperformance] 
    @Ecode nvarchar(50), 
    @startdate date,
    @enddate date
as 
begin 

    SELECT 
        e.Ecode,CAST(q.dtime AS DATE) as Date, 
        e.Ename, 
        count(q.Ecode) AS CntEcode ,
        count(DelEcode) AS CntDelEcode
    FROM EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
    inner JOIN Transaction_tbl q 
        ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode 
    where q.Ecode=@Ecode
        and @startdate <= dtime 
        and dtime < @enddate
    group by 
        e.Ecode, 
        e.Ename, 
        CAST(q.dtime AS date) 
    ORDER BY CAST(q.dtime AS date)--e.Ecode DESC
end
```

You shouldn't have problems with code that calls this stored procedure and passes `datetime` values because the time portions will be truncated. You will encounter problems only if you pass string literals instead of dates, in formats that SQL Server can't identify from your settings

If you have to use `datetime` parameters in some other part of your stored procedure, you can do a simple cast to date:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Driverperformance] 
    @Ecode nvarchar(50), 
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime
as 
begin 

    declare @date1 date= cast(@startdate as date);
    declare @date2 date= cast(@enddate as date);

    SELECT 
        e.Ecode,CAST(q.dtime AS DATE) as Date, 
        e.Ename, 
        count(q.Ecode) AS CntEcode ,
        count(DelEcode) AS CntDelEcode
    FROM EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
    inner JOIN Transaction_tbl q 
        ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode 
    where q.Ecode=@Ecode
        and @date1 <= dtime 
        and dtime < @date2
    group by 
        e.Ecode, 
        e.Ename, 
        CAST(q.dtime AS date) 
    ORDER BY CAST(q.dtime AS date)--e.Ecode DESC
end
```

You can also get rid of the `ORDER BY` statement by reordering your `GROUP BY`. Grouping orders the results, so you can use `GROUP BY CAST(q.dtime AS date) , e.Ecode, e.Ename` to get your results order by date, Ecode and Ename